# A filter for Gmail emails that come from x and have the subject either starting with y OR ending with z

Tags: gmail

I want to create a filter for messages that come from x and have the subject either starting with y OR ending with z.

I know the process of creating filters, however how do I specify `starting with y OR ending with z`?

PS: Currently I'm using `y | z` which is working "halfway" because it selects either y or z.

To rephrase the question, what should I type in the Subject box?

[image: Subject box example]

Comment: I think you're out of luck here. Filters don't allow for regex expressions and have very limited wildcard support. Apparently a lot of people would like such a feature, and you can [suggest they implement it](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=suggest).

Comment: what other wildcards do we have?

Comment: and does @Al works?

Comment: (Yes, "@Al" works.) Primarily just email addresses. `*@google.com` will capture any email at google.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand the question, but try:

```
from:x subject:y OR subject:z -subject:(y z)
```

Comment: That's not exactly what the OP wants. He wants something like `from:x subject:y other text in subject OR subject:other text in subject z`; where **y** and **z** can be anything.

Comment: Pacerier, ignore the boxes and try putting the query into the "has the words" field. As for the query itself, Gmail doesn't support wildcard searches at this time so you can't specify whether y or z are at the beginning or end of the subject. "subject:y OR subject:z" will turn up everything that has either y or z in the subject. "subject:y OR subject:z -subject:(y z)" will turn up anything that has only y, or only z, but not both y and z.

Comment: @Alex. Yes, Google really needs to buck up on better search operators. And we'd thought it's supposed to be a "search" company.... I can't even search for messages with a hyphen "-" in subject.